# Undefined reference error to linked class

Tags: c++, include, undefined-reference

For the life of me I can't figure out how to fix this linking issue. I set up a simple #include and I still get this same error. I know the IDE understands that the file is linked, because I get all sorts of other errors if I move the header file.

For the record I'm using the Propellor-GCC [SimpleIDE](http://learn.parallax.com/propeller-c-set-simpleide)

This is the entire project:

simplelink.cpp

```
#include "testclass.h"

int main(void)
{
  TestClass test1 = TestClass();

  return test1.value;
}
```

testclass.h (in the same directory as simplelink.cpp)

```
#ifndef _MYSIMPLELINK_
#define _MYSIMPLELINK_

struct TestClass {
  TestClass();

  int value;
};

#endif
```

testclass.c

```
#include "testclass.h"

TestClass::TestClass() {
  value = 13;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
propeller-elf-gcc.exe -v GCC 4.6.1 (propellergcc_v1_0_0_2162) propeller-elf-c++ -I . -L . -o cmm/simplelink.elf -Os -mcmm -Wall
-m32bit-doubles -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti simplelink.cpp 
C:\Users\Virtual\AppData\Local\Temp\cc81YpVR.o: In function `_main': 
(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `TestClass::TestClass()' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
Done. Build Failed!

Check source for bad function call or global variable name `TestClass::TestClass()'
```

Comment: rename `testclass.c` to `testclass.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

`testclass.c` should be `testclass.cpp`.

Also you need to link both `simplelink` and `testclass` into your executable. Appending `testclass.cpp` to your build string would do this, although you may want to have your makefile first build object files for each .cpp, and then link the object files.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to put a constructor into a `struct` when what you need is a `class`.

Change your TestClass definition to:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();

private:
    int value;
}
```

Then in `main`, instantiate a TestClass object with

```
TestClass test1 = new TestClass();
```

Also, as mentioned in other responses, rename `testclass.c` to `testclass.cpp` and build all the `.cpp` files before linking them.